# How to use cache for a child complex type property in IQueryable oData API C#

Tags: c#, api, caching, odata, iqueryable

I am working on oData API and I need the geographical data to cached base on the language code. I do not want to hit the database each time for that.

I have to return a list of offices and it has a property named GeoData which will have few properties e.g. Local Zone Name, City, Province and Country names based on the language code. The same offices list can have the Geodata in different languages.

I am not sure how I can achieve that as the repository by default returns IQueryable result that is the default convention of oData API.

Can anybody help me to achieve that. Thanks in advance.

Following is the code example:

```
public class OfficesController : ODataController
{
    IOfficeRepository _OfficeRepository;

    public OfficesController(IOfficeRepository officeRepository)
    {
        _OfficeRepository = officeRepository;
    }

    [EnableQuery(PageSize = 10, MaxTop = 25)]
    public IQueryable<Office> Get()
    {
        return _OfficeRepository.GetList();
    }
}


public interface IOfficeRepository
{
    IQueryable<Office> GetList(string langCode = "ENU");
}

public class OfficeRepository : BaseRepository, IOfficeRepository
{
    public IQueryable<Office> GetList(string langCode = "ENU")
    {
        IQueryable<Office> OfficeList =
            (from o in Context.tblOffices
             select new Office
             {
                 OfficeID = o.OfficeID,
                 OfficeName = o.OfficeName,
                 OfficeWebsite = o.URLToPrivatePage,
                 CompanyName = o.CompanyName,
                 Address = new OfficeAddress { Address1 = o.Address, Address2 = o.Address2, PostalCode = o.PostalCode },
                 Contacts = new OfficeContact { Email = o.Email, Fax = o.Fax, Phone = o.Phone, OfficeWebsite = o.URLToPrivatePage },
                 GeoData = new GEOData
                 {
                     LocalZoneID = o.LocalZoneId,
                     LocalZone = Cache.LocalZone(o.LocalZoneId),//Need this from cache
                     CityId = o.CityID,
                     City = Cache.CityName(o.CityID, langCode)//Need this from cache
                 }
             });

        return OfficeList;
    }
}
```